# Add Text To Text Area Using JS And Php String

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, textarea

I am trying to add a $string from php inside javascript to output a user's username inside a <\textarea>, I am looking for how to do what i am attempting but using JavaScript instead of Jquery as per example.

I also have not tested this, is the way I added php to the <\script> tag the correct method?

**Test.php**

```
// PHP STRINGS

    <?php
    if($_POST['hidden-post'] == 'hidden-post'){ 
    if($_POST['user-01'] == 'user-01'){ 
    $username = 'user01, ';
    }
    if($_POST['user-02'] == 'user-02'){ 
    $username = 'user02, ';
    }
    if($_POST['user-03'] == 'user-03'){ 
    $username = 'user03, ';
    }
    }
    ?>



// Convert from Jquery to JavaScript  

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#add").click(function(){
          $('#txtarea').html('<?php echo $username ?>');
      });
    });
    </script>


// HTML code to manipulate

    <tr>
    <td>
        <a id="add" target="_blank" href="http://domainname.com">DOMAINNAME.COM</a>
    </td>
    <td class="url-views">
        <textarea id="txtarea" name="url-views"></textarea>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
        <a id="add" target="_blank" href="http://domainname2.com">DOMAINNAME2.COM</a>
    </td>
    <td class="url-views">
        <textarea id="txtarea" name="url-views"></textarea>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code conversion service.

Comment: sorry I am not expert programmer and cannot aford to pay someone to do it for me. although I see plenty of posts on here how to do "this & that with javascript/jquery" I guess I could have worded it differently.... "how to add text to text area using js and php string"

Answer (score 0):

i saw your posted job on upwork and it's too silly to be honest to pay someone for this. moving forward, your question is not very clear as from what i understand you need to display the $username from php code to the textarea. is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I saw your job post in upwork .

## 1 JUST PUT IN THE TAG HTML.

// PHP STRINGS

```
<?php
if($_POST['hidden-post'] == 'hidden-post'){ 
if($_POST['user-01'] == 'user-01'){ 
$username = 'user01, ';
}
if($_POST['user-02'] == 'user-02'){ 
$username = 'user02, ';
}
if($_POST['user-03'] == 'user-03'){ 
$username = 'user03, ';
}
}
?>
```

// DELETE THIS CODE

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add").click(function(){
      $('#txtarea').html('<?php echo $username ?>');
  });
});
</script>
```

// DELETE THIS CODE

// HTML code to manipulate

```
<tr>
<td>
    <a id="add" target="_blank" href="http://domainname.com">DOMAINNAME.COM</a>
</td>
<td class="url-views">
    <textarea id="txtarea" name="url-views"><?php echo $username ?></textarea>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <a id="add" target="_blank" href="http://domainname2.com">DOMAINNAME2.COM</a>
</td>
<td class="url-views">
    <textarea id="txtarea" name="url-views"><?php echo $username ?></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
```

## 2 WITH JS NATIVE

// PHP STRINGS

```
<?php
if($_POST['hidden-post'] == 'hidden-post'){ 
if($_POST['user-01'] == 'user-01'){ 
$username = 'user01, ';
}
if($_POST['user-02'] == 'user-02'){ 
$username = 'user02, ';
}
if($_POST['user-03'] == 'user-03'){ 
$username = 'user03, ';
}
}
?>



<script>
      document.getElementById('txtarea').innerHTML = "<?php echo $username ?>"
</script>
```

// HTML code to manipulate

```
<tr>
<td>
    <a id="add" target="_blank" href="http://domainname.com">DOMAINNAME.COM</a>
</td>
<td class="url-views">
    <textarea id="txtarea" name="url-views"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <a id="add" target="_blank" href="http://domainname2.com">DOMAINNAME2.COM</a>
</td>
<td class="url-views">
    <textarea id="txtarea" name="url-views"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
```

HAVE A NICE DAY :D :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<script   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
// PHP STRINGS

<?php
if($_POST['hidden-post'] == 'hidden-post'){
    if($_POST['user-01'] == 'user-01'){
        $username = 'user01, ';
    }
    if($_POST['user-02'] == 'user-02'){
        $username = 'user02, ';
    }
    if($_POST['user-03'] == 'user-03'){
        $username = 'user03, ';
    }
}
?>



// Convert from Jquery to JavaScript

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add1").click(function(){
            $('#txtarea1').html('<?php echo $username ?>');
            $('#txtarea2').html('<?php echo $username ?>');
        });
        $("#add2").click(function(){
            $('#txtarea1').html('<?php echo $username ?>');
            $('#txtarea2').html('<?php echo $username ?>');
        });
    });
</script>


// HTML code to manipulate

<tr>
    <td>
        <a id="add1" target="_blank" href="http://domainname.com">DOMAINNAME.COM</a>
    </td>
    <td class="url-views">
        <textarea id="txtarea1" name="url-views" ></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <a id="add2"  target="_blank" href="http://domainname2.com">DOMAINNAME2.COM</a>
    </td>
    <td class="url-views">
        <textarea id="txtarea2" name="url-views"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: hi friend this is your code working i dont know what you expecting...but now its working...